# In R Shiny How to Separate Slider Input Values and Filter with them

Tags: r, widget, shiny

In R's `shiny` package you can have a slider widget using `sliderInput` that has an upper and lower bound.

I would like to be able to separate the upper and lower bound values and filter a column of data with them, before passing that data to `UI.R`.

For example:

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv('some_data_to_filter.csv')

# Define server logic for slider examples
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of
  # the values
  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("Range"),
      Value = as.character(c(paste(input$range, collapse=' '),)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 

  # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
})
```

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)    
# Define UI for slider demo application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #  Application title
  titlePanel("Sliders"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(      
  # Specification of range within an interval
      sliderInput("range", "Range:",
                  min = 1, max = 1000, value = c(200,500))
),

    # A table summarizing the values entered
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("values")
    )
  )
))
```

In the example above I read in the data and I have a slider, but there's no filtering of the data like I'd like there to be.

This was my best attempt to split and filter, but it throws an error:

```
myrange <- reactive({ data.frame(strsplit(Value = input$slider))})
data <- data[data$colname <= as.numeric(myrange[2]),]
data <- data[data$colname >= as.numeric(myrange[2]),]
```

Comment: Why would you need to `strsplit` `input$slider`, which is not a character vector?

Comment: The idea is to split the string that's produced but the slider range. The range/string produced by the slider object looks like this `"50 100"`. By using `data.frame(unlist(strsplit()))` you can normally transform that into separate elements of a vector in R, however the fact that this is reactive complicates things. Do you know of a way to separate the two numbers from `input$slider` so that they can be used to subset data?

Comment: I don't think you really need it. `input$range` is already a numeric vector of length two that contains minimum and maximum values, e.g. `num [1:2] 200 614`. That means that `input$range[1]` and `input$range[2]` will give you the left and right slider values.

Comment: OK, great! I think we are almost to a solution, but when I try it like this `data <- reactive({data[data$somecolumn <= input$range[2],]})` it says `Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: Please note that you are using `data` simultaneously as the name of the data set (`data <- read.csv('some_data_to_filter.csv')`) AND as the name of the reactive expression (`data <- reactive(...)`), which causes the error. Rename the reactive expression to something like `data.subset <- reactive(...)`.

Comment: @MaratTalipov I will, thank you. I *think* I only did that in the example that I sanitized for Stackoverflow, but I will make sure and I will update this thread.

Comment: @MaratTalipov So sorry, I could've sworn that I already posted a follow up comment. I ensured that the object names were different, but I still get the error.

Comment: could you upload the latest versions of your server.R and ui.R files?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question right you want to subset the data based on the two limits of the slider input right. If so, use the solution below with sample data

```
library(shiny)

# Sample Data
area <- seq(from=10,to=100, by=10);peri <- seq(from=2710.1,to=2800.1, by=10)
shape <- seq(from=0.1,to=1, by=0.1);perm <- seq(from=1,to=100, by=10)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(area,peri,shape,perm))

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(sliderInput("range", "Select Range",min = 1, max = 10, value = c(2, 5)),width = 3),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("view"))
)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderTable({
    test <- my_data[input$range[1]:input$range[2],]
    test},include.rownames=FALSE)
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```